# matSort is not working prperly

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm having trouble with mat-table and sorting data, I can't find the mistake.

There is a stackblitz example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lzhpvx

Can someone help me to see the mistake?

Comment: Please include the relevant information in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mistake is  with your column Template and Row Template The keys are in Uppercase

```
displayedColumns = ['EMAIL','ID'];
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
<ng-container matColumnDef="EMAIL">
                            ^^^^^^
```

Whereas in your data Array keys are in lower case

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: TestEmail[] = [
  {email: 'test1@test.com', id:4},
  {email: 'aaaatest2@test.com', id: 7},
  {email: 'oootest3@test.com', id: 1}
];
```

> A string with the name of that columns is assigned to this
>   `matColumnDef`directive. The directive uniquely identifies a given
>   column with a key and it should be same as defined in the data array
>   that provides data to the table.

**Modification:**

```
  displayedColumns = ['email','id'];

  <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o1rb4x)**
**P.S.** The **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lzhpvx)** Provided by you uses Latest version of Angular Material V6 and you have mixed it with Material V5